# Checking for non-numeric input and assigning to a double in C++?

Tags: c++

Here is the code I have at the moment:

```
char ch;
int sum = 0;
double values[10];
int i = 0;
cin >> ch;

while (!isalpha(ch))
{  
    values[i] = ch; 
    sum += values[i]; 
    i++;  
    cin >> ch;
}
```

What is happening is that if I enter the value 1, that gets assigned to ch as a char.  Now ch is assigning it's value to a double and doing an implicit cast.  So it is assigning the ASCII value of '1' to values[i].  I want it to just assign 1 to values[i].  Is there a better way to do this?  Or is there something that I'm missing?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to convert a digit character to its corresponding digit value, you can simply subtract `'0'` from it:

```
char ch = '2';
int value = ch - '0'; // value is 2
```

However, the best way to read in floating point numbers is just to extract `double`s from `cin`:

```
double value = 0;
if (cin >> value)
{
    // value is good
}
else
{
    // invalid value was entered; handle the error appropriately
}
```

Note that if the extraction fails and you want to continue reading from the stream, you will need to call `cin.clear()` to clear the fail state  of the stream and you may need to call `cin.ignore()` to ignore any trailing characters (for example, if you are using line-based input, you'll need to ignore everything until the next newline).

Comment: I think something just clicked for me.  So using your example, I could just do something like this?

if (cin >> isdigit(value))
{
    //value is good
}

Comment: No, and why would you do that? If `cin` cannot extract the value matching the type, it will be put into a fail state, and you won't enter the if branch.

Comment: @Brundle:  No... `isdigit()` tests whether a character is a digit; you can't `cin >> isdigit(value)`.  Just `cin >> value` where `value` is a `double` and it will attempt to read in and handle format conversion for a floating point value.  If it fails, then the `if` test will fail.  (Oh, GMan beat me to the explanation)

Comment: @Brundle I think what you're missing is the fact that `cin >> value` inherently determines whether the input is valid for the type of `value`. It's all implied by the overloaded `>>` operator.

Comment: Thanks, for the clear up with cin >> value in the if statement.  I tried changing my code to this and everything worked great.  I knew it was a little thing I was not understanding.

Answer (score 1):

Read the entire number as a string, and the convert the whole thing to a `double` by using the `strtod` function or some other C++-specific means.

Answer (score 1):

While this is not a good solution, you could technically subtract the ASCII code for '0' from your char variable when assigning the array element:

```
char ch;
int sum = 0;
double values[10];
int i = 0;
cin >> ch;
while (!isalpha(ch))
{  
    values[i] = ch - '0'; 
    sum += values[i]; 
    i++;  
    cin >> ch;
}
```

If ch was a number (0-9), then ch-'0' would give you that digit ch in "int" form ('0' is dec48 in an [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/), and the digits 0 to 9 are from dec48 to dec57).

This is a bit of a hack though, and probably shouldn't really be used, however, it is a possible solution.

Comment: Actually, it is required that the numbers are ordered sequentially in the execution character set, so the `ch - '0'` isn't really a hack at all (though there are usually better ways to handle input).

Answer (score 0):

string stream should be able to do the conversion for you.  A pass through atoi could also get the job done.