# Is there a stl or boost function to determine if a string is numeric?

Tags: c++, boost, stl

I'm very new to C++, boost etc.

I would like to know if there is already a function in boost or STL I can use to determine if a string is numeric.

Numeric strings may look like:
100

or

100.52

I know there are tons of examples how to write such a function but I would like to know if there is already a function I can use for this.

I'm looking for a pure C++-solution, not C.

[UPDATE:
I'm already using lexical_cast to convert my strings, I'm just wondering if there is a method like is_numeric I can use for this...]

Comment: Just wondering, what's wrong with a C solution?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010481/

Comment: @Mehrdad: I don't like mixing C with C++. Just a personal point of view.

Comment: Thanks for voting up my comment, whoever did it... :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, there's not a ready-made way to do this directly.

You could use `boost::lexical_cast<double>(your_string)` or `std::stod(your_string)` and if it throws an exception then your string is not a double.

C++11:

```
    bool is_a_number = false;
    try
    {
        std::stod(your_string);
        is_a_number = true;
    }
    catch(const std::exception &)
    {
        // if it throws, it's not a number.
    }
```

Boost:

```
    bool is_a_number = false;
    try
    {
        lexical_cast<double>(your_string);
        is_a_number = true;
    }
    catch(bad_lexical_cast &)
    {
        // if it throws, it's not a number.
    }
```

Comment: This is a quick solution. There is considerable overhead in doing this (copies + stringstreams + exceptions), and this kind of stuff is often used in loops. Moreover, exception fascists will tell you that you're using an exception for flow control and not for exceptional cases.

Comment: @Alexandre Sure, and very worth pointing out, but the OP didn't list any efficiency constraints.

Comment: Hi Alexandre, Hi Matt, I justed wanted to know if I have to invent the wheel :). But nonetheless your advice is very welcome, Alexandre!

Comment: @Inno Sure! It does seem like the kitchen sink is hidden inside the standard library and boost, but when you take a look under the sink some of the pipes aren't connected :-)

Comment: This is correct but probably outdated/overkill since C++11. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60075448/1753435) for modern C++.

Answer (score 9):

`boost::regex` (or `std::regex`, if you have C++0x) can be used;
you can defined what you want to accept (e.g. in your context,
is "0x12E" a number or not?).  For C++ integers:

```
"\\s*[+-]?([1-9][0-9]*|0[0-7]*|0[xX][0-9a-fA-F]+)"
```

For C++ floating point:

```
"\\s*[+-]?([0-9]+\\.[0-9]*([Ee][+-]?[0-9]+)?|\\.[0-9]+([Ee][+-]?[0-9]+)?|[0-9]+[Ee][+-]?[0-9]+)"
```

But depending on what you're doing, you might not need to
support things that complex.  The two examples you cite would be
covered by

```
"[0-9]+(\\.[0-9]*)?"
```

for example.

If you're going to need the numeric value later, it may also be
just as easy to convert the string into an `istringstream`, and
do the convertion immediately.  If there's no error, and you
extract all of the characters, the string was a number; if not,
it wasn't.  This will give you less control over the exact
format you want to accept, however.

Answer (score 6):

If performance is a concern *at all*, I would use [boost](http://www.boost.org/).[spirit](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/spirit/index.html).[qi](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/tutorials/quick_start.html) rather than `std::stringstream`:

```
#include <string>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi_parse.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi_numeric.hpp>

bool is_numeric(std::string const& str)
{
    std::string::const_iterator first(str.begin()), last(str.end());
    return boost::spirit::qi::parse(first, last, boost::spirit::double_)
        && first == last;
}
```

If you want to allow trailing whitespace then do the following instead:

```
#include <string>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi_parse.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi_numeric.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi_char_class.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi_operator.hpp>

bool is_numeric(std::string const& str)
{
    std::string::const_iterator first(str.begin()), last(str.end());
    return boost::spirit::qi::parse(first, last,
            boost::spirit::double_ >> *boost::spirit::qi::space)
        && first == last;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for drawing my attention to this.  I'll keep it in mind for cases where boost::lexical_cast (and thus std::stringstream) might be a little to heavyweight.

Comment: @arr_sea : Bear in mind that the modern recommendation would be for Spirit.X3 rather than Spirit.Qi unless you're stuck with C++03. :-]

Answer (score 3):

Use a `stringstream` and return `true` if the convertion "ate" all the characters in the original string (=`eof()`).

```
bool is_numeric(const std::string& str) {
    std::stringstream conv;
    double tmp;
    conv << str;
    conv >> tmp;
    return conv.eof();
}
```

Comment: Is checking eof() really the Right Thing to do ?

Comment: @Stefan: yes. @Helltone: This can be done in one or two lines: `( std::istringstream( str ) >> num ).ws().eof()`. Note the call to `ws` to strip off trailing spaces, this is optional. (However, this shortcut misses empty or all-whitespace strings. Likewise, your more complete implementation should return `conv && conv.eof()`.)

Comment: @Stefan In this case, it's probably appropriate; I'd use `return conv.get() == EOF;` but the difference is probably one of style more than anything else.

Comment: This is actually what lexical_cast does.

Comment: @James Kanze OK. That way you don't get a false positive for '2.5a'.

Comment: @Alexandr C. Except that `lexical_cast` reports the error via an exception; if I understand the question, this is not an exceptional case.  Adding the necessary try/catch code ends up requiring as many lines as doing the job yourself.  (On the other hand, `lexical_cast` does the job correctly; if you don't know `iostream` that well---and judging from other questions and answers, a lot of people don't---then that may be an important point to consider.)

Answer (score 3):

```
bool is_numeric(std::string number)
{
    char* end = 0;
    std::strtod(number.c_str(), &end);

    return end != 0 && *end == 0;
}


bool is_integer(std::string number)
{
    return is_numeric(number.c_str()) && std::strchr(number.c_str(), '.') == 0;
}
```

[Source](http://www.rsdn.ru/forum/cpp/4311493.flat.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

The following code

The following sentense, return true if "str" is composed of 0~9 only, otherwise, return false.

```
return str.find_first_not_of("0123456789") == std::string::npos
```

Comment: Please explain your answer and the code also when posting answers.

Answer (score 2):

You could try a [lexical_cast](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/conversion/lexical_cast.htm) on the string.

Answer (score 1):

From C++11, you can simply use one of `std::stof`, `std::stod`, `std::stold` for converting to `float`, `double` and `long double`, respectively. They convert a string to the numerical value or throw an exception, if there's a problem (see [the reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof)). Here is an example with `std::stod`:

```
bool isNumeric(const std::string& str) {
  try {
    std::stod(str); // can safely ignore the return value, function is not [[nodiscard]]
    return true;
  }
  catch (const std::exception&) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Also have a look at the functions to convert a string to [signed](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) and [unsigned](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stoul) integers.

Comment: The problem is that this will return true for strings like "123aa" also

Answer (score 0):

There is no boost needed, only stl ...
A single char could be checked as an int (c >= '0' && c <= '9'), find_if_not will find the first char not matching the condition between [first] and [last]. If no match was found, it will return [last].

If additional chars like space,.- should be checked, add them.

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
bool isNumeric(std::string strValue) 
{
    if (strValue.empty())
        return false;
    else
        return (std::find_if_not( std::begin(strValue)
                            , std::end(strValue)
                            , [](char c)
                              { return (c >= '0' && c <= '9'); }
                            ) == std::end(strValue)
                );
}
```

P.S.
@Jian Hu is an empty string numeric ?