# How to read from cin until something non-numeric is entered?

Tags: c++, input

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<limits>
#include<stdexcept>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    size_t i;
    int numVals;
    int min;

    vector<int> sequence(numVals);
    min = sequence.at(i);

    cout << "sequence: ";     
    for (i=0; i<sequence.size(); ++i)
    {            
        cin >> sequence.at(i);
        if (cin.bad()){
            break;
        }
        if (sequence.at(i) < min){
            min = sequence.at(i);
            cout << min << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I want the program to keep reading integers from cin until something non-numeric like 'q' is entered. I want to find the second smallest from a sequence. Therefore the user should give sequence of integers. the user should stop the sequence with q. how can I fix this?

Comment: What isn't working? Did  you make sure that all variables are initialized before they are used? Wouldn't it be more sensible to append a successfully read value to the  `sequence` instead of assuming that the `sequence` is somehow large enough?

Comment: Note that `bad()` gets set when something substantial goes wrong with the stream, e.g., no stream buffer is set. For problems with the format `std::ios_base::failbit` is set. When  testing for `fail()` both `std::ios_base::failbit` and  `std::ios_base::badbit` get  tested.

Comment: Re: `sequence.at(i)` -- inside the loop, you **know** that `i` is in bounds, because you wrote it that way. There's no need to check it. As for the first one, since `i` has not been assigned any value, you **know** that it's not valid, so also shouldn't test it; just get rid of that line.

Comment: In the current version, `min` is initialized to 0.

Comment: Also see [Checking for non-numeric input and assigning to a double in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3010481/608639). The same technique should work with your question.

Comment: `i` is uninitialized when you use it at `min = sequence.at(i);`.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (std::cin)
    // Input succeeded 

if (!std::cin)
    // Input failed
```

Try incorporating this somewhere in your code.